# Slightly more informative error messages when the title is too long

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, titles, character-limit

Titles are limited to 150 characters. This is a reasonable limitations, but with $\rm\LaTeX$ one can easily go beyond that. Since it is impossible to a priori judge the length of the compiled $\rm\LaTeX$, I'm not asking for this limitation to be changed.

However when editing a title and going beyond the 150 letters, one can only know that the title is too long. There is no indication of **how long** is the current title. If I have to remove one letter it is different from removing an entire word.

I had recently brushed with this feature (again) which made me unnecessarily angry at the computer for not telling me how long the title I was editing was.

> Is it possible to add a character count to the title, or at least a count of current title in the error message when it comes up?

---

Nearly five years later: can we get ***any*** response to that from the higher power that is SE?

Comment: (I've added the [status-review] tag to help and push this into the work queue. A similar feature request was made earlier today.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now (thanks to your request), there is a new feature released network-wide (including Stack Overflow for Teams) where users will be shown a character count starting when the Title hits 100 characters.

The count will appear above the right end of the Title input box and will function in the same way as the character counter used elsewhere on the site (most prominently with comments):

[image: Illustration showing the character counter both when approaching and after passing the character limit]

When you go over the limit, an error state will show on the box. The character count will update as changes are made to the title. The counter will count actual text in the box (so if you are including something like LaTeX in the title, it will count the number of character before rendering it).

Comment: $$\Huge{\bf Yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}$$

Comment: Better late than never, right? I gave y'all a shoutout on the [MSE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362263/51) as well.

Comment: Thanks, again. This was a thorn in my side for over a decade now.

Answer (score 13):

We are putting this into our bug-duty rotation and should get to this within a few weeks. (Sorry it's taken 8+ years!)

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!